# Reusing Geometry causes Intermittent THREE.JS Texture Error

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am creating my first game (Card Game) with THREE.js for Firefox and Chrome and I am currently stuck with an intermittent error that makes some of my textures invisible.

My object with this post is to understand why this is happening so I can work on a solution. I will be adding my questions at the end of the post.

It happens with more frequency when I switch browser tabs before the scene is loaded.

I already checked my code to validate if I was setting new materials to already loaded meshes in the scene and it wasnt the case.

I am using specular maps with foil cards, and I tried with no success the related solutions here in Stack Overflow. I also tried to remove the specular maps.

I also read about setting the update flags for materials being added after the object is in the scene and it didn't work either.

There were similar posts I also looked into, but these two summed up the options I had to try to solve the problem.

The error:

```
256 [.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0 
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

The card object creation steps:
1 - Create a base geometry on the game load 
2 - Reuse it for all the cards being created

Base Geometry Creation (The vertex/face manipulation is to create a black-grey-black gradient for the borders with vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors):

```
(function createGeometry () {
DBZCCG.Card.backTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
    "images/DBZCCG/back.jpg");

DBZCCG.Card.cubeGeo = 
    new THREE.CubeGeometry(
        DBZCCG.Card.cardWidth, 
        DBZCCG.Card.cardHeight, 
        DBZCCG.Card.cardDepth
    );

/* Vertex and face alterations */
var cube = DBZCCG.Card.cubeGeo;
var vertices = cube.vertices;
var faces = cube.faces;

vertices.push(vertices[7].clone());
vertices.push(vertices[5].clone());
vertices.push(vertices[0].clone());
vertices.push(vertices[2].clone());

vertices[5].color = vertices[0].color = vertices[2].color = vertices[7].color
        = new THREE.Color(0x777777);

vertices[5].z = vertices[0].z = vertices[2].z = vertices[7].z = 0;

faces[8].a = 9;
faces[8].b = 8;
faces[8].c = 10;

faces[9].a = 8;
faces[9].b = 11;
faces[9].c = 10;

faces.push(new THREE.Face3(9, 5, 7));
faces.push(new THREE.Face3(9, 7, 8));

faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 10, 2));
faces.push(new THREE.Face3(10, 11, 2));

faces.push(new THREE.Face3(8, 7, 2));
faces.push(new THREE.Face3(8, 2, 11));

faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 9, 0));
faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 9, 10));

for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    if (vertices[faces[i].a].color === undefined) {
        faces[i].vertexColors[0] = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
    } else {
        faces[i].vertexColors[0] = vertices[faces[i].a].color;
    }

    if (vertices[faces[i].b].color === undefined) {
        faces[i].vertexColors[1] = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
    } else {
        faces[i].vertexColors[1] = vertices[faces[i].b].color;
    }

    if (vertices[faces[i].c].color === undefined) {
        faces[i].vertexColors[2] = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
    } else {
        faces[i].vertexColors[2] = vertices[faces[i].c].color;
    }
}

})();
```

And here is the function to create the card:

```
function createCard(texturePath) {
        var card = new THREE.Object3D();
        DBZCCG.loadCounter++;
        var frontTexture = texturePath ? 
            THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(texturePath,
            THREE.UVMapping,
            DBZCCG.incrementLoad) 
            : null;
        DBZCCG.loadCounter++;
        var specularMap =
            THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
                'images/DBZCCG/saiyan/specularmap.jpg',
                THREE.UVMapping, DBZCCG.incrementLoad);

        var cardCoverBackMaterials = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cardCoverBackMaterials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                    {
                        transparent: true,
                        emissive: 0xFFFFFF,
                        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
                    })); // sides
        }

        cardCoverBackMaterials[4] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                {
                    transparent: true,
                    emissive: 0xFFFFFF,
                    map: DBZCCG.Card.backTexture
                }); // back

        cardCoverBackMaterials[5] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
            {
                transparent: true,
                reflectivity: dataObject.foil ? 
                    dataObject.foil.reflectivity : 1,
                specularMap: specularMap,
                envMap: dataObject.foil ? dataObject.foil.texture : null,
                emissive: 0xFFFFFF,
                map: frontTexture
            }); // front

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cardCoverBackMaterials.push(
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                   transparent: true,
                   emissive: 0xFFFFFF
            })); // sides
        }

        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
            DBZCCG.Card.cubeGeo, 
            new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(cardCoverBackMaterials));

        card.add(cube);

        return card;
    }
```

Questions:

1 - Is there anything that I can do to try to solve this?

2 - Is this related to the scene being rendered before the objects have been added to the scene?

3 - Is this related to the scene being rendered before the textures got loaded?

4 - For Q2 and Q3 I tried to add a load check with window intervals. I still got the error from time to time.

5 - Is there an option to catch an webgl error and render everything again? Is this a good option?

TL/DR; There's an intermittent WebGL error in my code happening on load. I am using THREE.js.

Thank you

THREE.js r66

EDIT:
I'm adding two screenshots, one with the error and one with everything normal.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv8Pk.jpg)

[One reload later, everything is normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGK31.jpg)

---

EDIT AFTER SOLVING:

Basically I was using the same geometry for all the Card Objects on the scene.

I just changed:

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(DBZCCG.Card.cubeGeo, 
new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(cardCoverBackMaterials));
```

Into:

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(DBZCCG.Card.cubeGeo.clone(), 
new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(cardCoverBackMaterials));
```

Shouldnt I be reusing the same geometry?

I still do not understand why it made the error go away and I would like an explanation on why it solved the bug (and maybe why it was causing it as well).

When I made a 50-line code trying to reproduce the error, I was reusing the geometry and the  error never happened. I was also using the same function to create the object that generated problems.

Comment: Can you produce a 50-line program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I produced a 50-line program doing the exact same steps I highlighted in my question, but the 50-line program didnt produced the error at all. I could provide screenshots showing the output of the working version and when the error happens. However, if this is turning into a 'help-me-debug-my-program', I understand there's nothing that could be answered to me and I will remove my question.

Comment: I'll be glad to try to help you if I can. Try to reproduce the problem with a simple example. Are you adding a texture during runtime when there was no texture before?

Comment: No. I saw your previous answers to people that had a similar problem and checked for that. In the sample I posted, it creates all the code and after everything is created it starts to render.

I only have these hints at this time:
1- Not adding the card objects into the scene doesnt create the problem at all.
2 - In the new code, only adding the objects to the scene never caused the problem to happen.

Comment: I was able to solve the bug, but I need to understand now why it happened.

Answer (score 2):

I would try using callbacks with the onLoad event to control the timing and execution of your code. For instance change

```
 DBZCCG.Card.backTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
   "images/DBZCCG/back.jpg");
```

to

```
 DBZCCG.Card.backTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
   "images/DBZCCG/back.jpg", new THREE.UVMapping(), function() { ... } );
```

Use the callback functions to insure loading has completed before progressing.

Hey sorry for the delay I haven't logged onto stack in a bit. I think the issue here is you were trying to apply multiple textures to the same geometry. I would think they should just over wright each other but I guess not. Cloning the geometry allowed each texture to be applied to it's own object. Or at least that's my take on things.

Comment: Already changed that. I added an onLoad callback that counts the textures i'm trying to add to the game and I have a window.interval before checking if the expected number of textures has been reached. Only after that I progress to render the game. Also, I added a console.log call in the onError callback. Nothing extra showed up in the console with the onError function when the error happens. I'm trying to minify the code now. I rebuild the scene from scratch and it didnt showed any errors. Trying to strip the scene from all the elements except the ones with errors kept the errors happening.

Comment: The error persists. My attempts on solving it were minifying the css and js, plus caching the textures instead of creating new ones.

Comment: I was able to solve the bug, but I need to understand now why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

I did something that made the error never happen again.

I'm editing my question, since I desire to understand why it happened.